# goでのデコレーターとストラテジーの実装について

Tags: go

goでストラテジーパターンを用いてある処理のふるまいを変更していました。
すべての具体的なストラテジーに対して、付加的な処理を入れる場合と入れない場合が出てきたので、デコレーターパターンを用いて対応を検討しました。chatgptに質問すると、下記のように、インターフェースを埋め込むことで対応できることがわかりました。この場合、デコレーター構造体側でストラテジーの大元のインターフェースのメソッドをすべて実装しないとデコレーターがストラテジーインターフェースを満たしてくれませんでした。ほとんど委譲しかしないメソッドを定義しないとならないのですが(下記の例で言うと、Refundのようなメソッドが大量にあるイメージです。)、これは仕方のないことでしょうか。

ほかにgoらしいスマートなやり方があれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
package main

import "fmt"

// 支払い方法のストラテジー
type PaymentStrategy interface {
    Pay(amount float64) string
    Refund(amount float64) string
}

// クレジットカード支払い
type CreditCardStrategy struct{}

func (c *CreditCardStrategy) Pay(amount float64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("クレジットカードで %.2f 円支払いました", amount)
}

func (c *CreditCardStrategy) Refund(amount float64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("クレジットカードで %.2f 円返金しました", amount)
}

// 手数料デコレーター
type FeeDecorator struct {
    strategy PaymentStrategy
    fee      float64
}

func (d *FeeDecorator) Pay(amount float64) string {
    totalAmount := amount + d.fee
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s（手数料 %.2f 円込み）", d.strategy.Pay(totalAmount), d.fee)
}

func (d *FeeDecorator) Refund(amount float64) string {
    // 手数料デコレーターはRefundメソッドに手数料を加える必要はないため、そのまま委譲する
    return d.strategy.Refund(amount)
}

func main() {
    creditCard := &CreditCardStrategy{}
    creditCardWithFee := &FeeDecorator{strategy: creditCard, fee: 2.0}

    fmt.Println(creditCardWithFee.Pay(100.0))
    fmt.Println(creditCardWithFee.Refund(50.0))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

埋め込みはこう書くのでは？

```
// 手数料デコレーター
type FeeDecorator struct {
    PaymentStrategy
    fee float64
}

func (d *FeeDecorator) Pay(amount float64) string {
    totalAmount := amount + d.fee
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s（手数料 %.2f 円込み）", d.PaymentStrategy.Pay(totalAmount), d.fee)
}

func main() {
    creditCard := &CreditCardStrategy{}
    creditCardWithFee := &FeeDecorator{PaymentStrategy: creditCard, fee: 2.0}

    fmt.Println(creditCardWithFee.Pay(100.0))
    fmt.Println(creditCardWithFee.Refund(50.0))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/ZrtdKT3q4IP

Comment: 確かに、埋め込むという表現は不適切でした。インターフェースを保持させる、ですね。

Comment: 英語だと[embedding](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding)なので埋め込みでいいと思います。表現はともかく、これで目的は達成できますよね？

Comment: うまくいきました。ありがとうございます。